# How I can detect when user tap on part of screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have some problem with constrian layout. My apps looks like this:
[image]

A root layout is a ConstraintLayout. I want detect when user click on "A" part of screen. How can achive this? When i put onClick attribute on root ConstraintLayout I also detect whe user click on "B" part of screen but I dont want this. On part "B" I also use a Constrainlayout tu put some butons and to animate it.

Comment: how about putting an onClick listener on part A constraintLayout ?

Comment: you can retrieve the layout height and width and with that you can decide the constraints of the touch. From onTouch method you can get user tap location, and now use the above contraintsand apply the logic and do something if your touch coordinates satisfies the constraints

Comment: Place an empty view at A and give clicklistner for it

Answer (score 0):

You should create separate child layouts for part "A" and part "B", then add `onClickListener` to both of these elements.

Then your layout tree should look somewhat like this.

```
<ConstraintLayout>

<ViewA/>
<ViewB/>

<ConstraintLayout/>
```

Comment: I don't need a viewB because i want to only detect clic on part "A". 
But other views (such as TextViews, ImagesView) had to be inside <ViewA> ?

Comment: Then start looking into `OnTouchListener`. It will give you the location of each touch then you can check if the touched points(x,y) is inside your ViewA.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate layout for your view A and in your activity add a TouchListener to your view :

```
 ConstraintLayout mViewA = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutViewA);
 //the view becomes sensitive to touch
 mViewA.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Layout touched",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```